# Break ties using rank function (OR other function) PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rank

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID Name    Weight Score  
1  Amazon    2    11     
1  Apple     4    10     
1  Netflix   1    10     
2  Amazon    2    8      
2  Apple     4    8      
2  Netflix   1    5
```

Currently I have a code which looks like this

```
#add weight and score column
df['Rank'] = df['Weight'] + df['Score']
#create score rank on ID column
df['Score_Rank'] = df.groupby('ID')['Rank'].rank("first", ascending = False)
```

This code does not give me exactly what I want.

I would like to first rank on Score, without including the weight. And then break any ties in the rank by adding weight column to break them.
If there are further ties after weight column has been added, then rank would be by random selection.

I think an if statement could work in this scenario, just not sure how.

Expected output:

```
ID Name    Weight Score  Score_Rank
1  Amazon    2    11     1
1  Apple     4    10     2
1  Netflix   1    10     3
2  Amazon    2    8      2
2  Apple     4    8      1
2  Netflix   1    5      3
```

Comment: So if score and weight is tied the ranks should be different for those rows (I.e, one would be rank 3 the other would be rank 4), or would they be the same (so both 3)?

Comment: One would be rank 3, and the other would be rank 4. In the case were both are tied, we would select rank randomly - only after ranking on score alone first, then score + weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `cumcount`:

```
df['Score_Rank'] = (df.sort_values(['Score','Weight'])
                      .groupby(['ID']).cumcount(ascending=False)+1
                   )
```

Output:

```
   ID     Name  Weight  Score  Score_Rank
0   1   Amazon       2     11           1
1   1    Apple       4     10           2
2   1  Netflix       1     10           3
3   2   Amazon       2      8           2
4   2    Apple       4      8           1
5   2  Netflix       1      5           3
```

Comment: Could you briefly describe what this does?

Comment: @tjjudge it does what you wanted: First sort by `Score`, then by `Weight` if `Score` is tied, finally use `cumcount` to enumerate the rows accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `rank` with `method='first'` with some presorting first:

```
df['Score_Rank'] = (df.sort_values('Weight', ascending=False)
                      .groupby(['ID'])['Score']
                      .rank(method='first', ascending=False)
                   )
```

Output:

```
   ID     Name  Weight  Score  Score_Rank
0   1   Amazon       2     11         1.0
1   1    Apple       4     10         2.0
2   1  Netflix       1     10         3.0
3   2   Amazon       2      8         2.0
4   2    Apple       4      8         1.0
5   2  Netflix       1      5         3.0
```

*Details:*

First, sort your dataframe by weights descending, then use rank with method first on Score which will break ties based on sort order of the dataframe. And because, pandas does intrinsic data alignment, assign to new column 'Score_Rank' yeilds the based on original order of the dataframe.